# Javascript parameter help needed

Tags: javascript

I've this function:

```
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var sl = $(this).scrollLeft();
    var lbl = $("#waypoints");
    if (sl > 0) {
        lbl.show('');
    }
    else {
        lbl.hide();
    }
    if (sl > 750) {
        lbl.html("<p>now passed 750</p>");
    }
    if (sl > 1000) {
        lbl.html("<p>now passed 1000</p>");
    }
});
```

});

Which work when i scroll the browser window. But I need to adjust it, so that it is set for a div (#main) which scrolls inside another div (.content) which has a fixed width and css overflow enabled.

I've tried  `$(#main).scroll(function(e) {` no joy ...

thanks for reading, any help would be awesome.

Comment: It's suppose to be scrolled vertically?

Comment: Can you post some HTML or a Fiddle?

Comment: Guess you are only missing apostrophes `$('#main').scroll(...` seems 2 b an easy fix. And also you can reorder it to this: `if (sl > 1000) {...} else if (sl > 750) {...}` to prevent that double overwritting ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change to class:

```
$(function() {
    $('.content').scroll(function(e) {
        var sl = $(this).scrollLeft();
        var lbl = $("#waypoints");
        if (sl > 0) {
            lbl.show();
        }
        else {
            lbl.hide();
        }
        if (sl > 750) {
            lbl.html("<p>now passed 750</p>");
        }
        if (sl > 1000) {
            lbl.html("<p>now passed 1000</p>");
        }
    });
});​
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njZnP/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's the problem here - it's working (I mean the scroll events are fired, as you can see by scrollLeft value that is changing) http://jsfiddle.net/DTKeX/2/